# Problem Approach: uncertainty about sample size

Tags: sample-size, small-sample, method-comparison

I have a time series of events (weekly aggregate date)
Each event is information on contracts closed by a sales representatives during working weeks.
The goal is to calculate what is the expected number of contracts that should be closed by a sales representative operating in a certain city, basing the analysis on historical data.

The issues faced:

- There's no way to know if a sales rep was working, on holiday, ill. It
  is hard to close contracts, so the possibility that a working sales
  rep does not close on a deal is high. If a salesmen worked but closed no contracts, it will not show up on the dataset.
- Some salesmen have working contracts with very variable number of working hours. It may be possible that they are on 50% workloads. No info of that in the dataset.
- In certain cities more than 100 reps can be active simultaneously, in other small cities office headcount might be only 10 or 20 reps, some very small cities have one or two salesmen working there. So in some cases it does not make sense to just "average"  spreading holidays and illness periods over the sample.

What methodology might well be tried out in an attempt to tackle this problem?
Thanks.